# when I define a forigen key for prodecure i get error

Tags: oracle

```
Create Table table10_prc (

      Family    VARCHAR2(200),
    
      Name      VARCHAR2(200) ,
      
      ID        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
     
      NAME_ID    INTEGER   ;
   

) ;


CREATE SEQUENCE ID_seq3
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1 ;
   
  
Create or Replace trigger trg3 
  BEFORE insert on  table10_prc 
  
   for each row 
   BEGIN
   select ID_seq3.nextval INTO :new.ID from dual ;
   END ;
 
   


 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem4 (str IN VARCHAR2)
 FOREIGN KEY INTEGER REFERENCES table10_prc(ID);
   AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table10_prc (Name, Family,NAME_ID)
          WITH
            temp
             AS
               (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                           '[^,]+',
                                          1,
                                        LEVEL) val
                    FROM DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, ',') + 1)
         SELECT NAME_ID,TRIM(SUBSTR(val, 1, INSTR (val, ';') - 1)),
               TRIM(SUBSTR(val, INSTR (val, ';') + 1))
          FROM temp;
 
      COMMIT;
   END;
 
 
 
   
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_member (par_id IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM table10_prc
         WHERE id = par_id;
END;


   

 BEGIN
       addnewmem4 ('faezeh;Ghanbarian,pari;izadi');
    END;
    
BEGIN
       addnewmem4 ('Saeed;Izadi,Saman; Rostami');
       
    END; 
    
 BEGIN
 
 delete_member (1);
 
 END;
 
 BEGIN
 
 delete_member (2) ;
 
 END;
 
 CALL delete_member(5);
 
 CALL delete_member(6);

   
 select *
 from  table10_prc ;
```

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: In the first `CREATE TABLE` statement, `NAME_ID    INTEGER   ;` should not have the trailing `;` also you need to terminate every PL/SQL block with a `/` on a newline after each block's final `END;` statement.

Comment: Procedure (executable code) cannot have any foreign key (what part of code may reference some table?). See [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54)

Comment: You have not asked a question and procedures cannot have foreign keys so your title does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> when I define a forigen key for prodecure i get error

This:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem4 (str IN VARCHAR2)
 FOREIGN KEY INTEGER REFERENCES table10_prc(ID);
   AS
```

is invalid. Foreign keys belong to **tables**, not procedures.